# Why does the tkinter entry not compare with password

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-entry

This is my code:

```
def masterpassgui(password):

    masterpassword = password
    add_window = tk.Tk()
    add_window.title("Master Password")
    add_window.geometry("250x250")
    masterpass_label = tk.Label(add_window, text="Enter your master password:")
    masterpass_label.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="w")
    masterpass_entry = tk.Entry(add_window)
    masterpass_entry.grid(row=0, column=1)
    masterpass = masterpass_entry.get()
    attempts = 5
    def on_click():
        messagebox.showwarning(f"You have {attempts} attempts left. After that it will lock down.")
    while masterpass != masterpassword:
    masterpass_label = tk.Label(add_window, text="Enter your master password:")
    masterpass_label.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="w")
        masterpass_entry = tk.Entry(add_window)
        masterpass_entry.grid(row=0, column=1)
        masterpass = masterpass_entry.get()
        if masterpass != masterpassword:
            attempts -= 1
            if attempts == 0:
                sys.exit()
            else:
                on_click()
        else:
            break
    add_window.mainloop()`
```

I am trying to make a password manager, but it is getting stuck on this piece of code.

I was expecting for it ask my master password, and if it was wrong, it would give me a warning, saying that you have some amount of attempts left. Instead, it just give me 5 consecutive warning messages, and then shuts down. Why is this happening?

Comment: With your current indentation it's impossible to answer

Comment: is this better @roganjosh?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code, the `masterpass` variable is not updated inside the loop, so it's always checking against the initial empty string. Additionally, the `get()` method retrieves the content of the entry widget at the time it is called, not dynamically as the user types.

I have modified like:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox
import sys

def masterpassgui(password):
    masterpassword = password
    add_window = tk.Tk()
    add_window.title("Master Password")
    add_window.geometry("250x250")
    
    masterpass_label = tk.Label(add_window, text="Enter your master password:")
    masterpass_label.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="w")
    masterpass_entry = tk.Entry(add_window)
    masterpass_entry.grid(row=0, column=1)
    
    attempts = 5

    def on_click():
        messagebox.showwarning(f"You have {attempts} attempts left. After that, it will lock down.")

    def check_password():
        nonlocal attempts
        masterpass = masterpass_entry.get()
        if masterpass != masterpassword:
            attempts -= 1
            if attempts == 0:
                sys.exit()
            else:
                on_click()
        else:
            add_window.destroy()

    submit_button = tk.Button(add_window, text="Submit", command=check_password)
    submit_button.grid(row=1, columnspan=2)

    add_window.mainloop()

# Example usage
masterpassgui("your_master_password")
```